# Sitelock .unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had done some modifications to unity games (like infinite ammo, player invincible) using .net reflector thru reflexil plugin & hosted on my domain.

Can I sitelock .unity3d files to my domain & how

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just about hacking, not actual engineering.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to check the domain in the code (best result check in the first scene) so that if it not on your chosen URL then then can do a different action (i.e. redirect, display a message)

[This manual page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html)
should show what you need and

```
Application.ExternalEval("if(document.location.host != 'YOURDOMAIN.COM') { document.location='WHERE_TO_REDIRECT_YOUR_USER; }");
```

will push them back to your site each time. You could increase this to report back to you as well and you would have a log of sites hosting incorrectly it required.

Answer (score 3):

I [wrote a script that will](http://otakunozoku.com/unity3d-piracy-prevention/) "lock your Unity3D game to a specific list of websites."

An updated version is [also available on GitHub](https://github.com/JustinLloyd/unity-anti-piracy) and also, [identically on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/JustinLloyd/unity-anti-piracy/)

From the readme.md

A C# script for Unity 3D that prevents your Web Player project from running on
websites that are not authorised.



Answer (score 1):

You may also need to check that the game is not embedded in another site using an iframe.

When dealing with frames you can't access a page from a different domain.

This actually means we don't even need to check the host of the outer page, because if we can even access it then we know it's from the same domain anyway.

So this will redirect someone if your page is not being embedded in a page with the same host:

```
Application.ExternalEval(
    "if(parent && parent.document == undefined) 
    { 
       window.top.location.replace('http://goo.gl/9ulDD'); 
    }"
);
```

If you really do need to check the exact URL (for example, you're hosting the page on foo.com and you want bar.com to be able to embed your content) then you can check the document.referrer, which is set to the URL of the page that includes the frame:

```
Application.ExternalEval(
        "if (parent) 
         {
                var pathParts = document.referrer.split('/');
                if (pathParts[2] != '" + locktoSite + "')
                        window.top.location.replace('http://goo.gl/9ulDD');
        }"
);
```